# Inside ui-grid column definitions , how to add a button to upload image. angular.element(this).scope().function is not triggering in controller

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, ui-grid

inside ui-grid column definotions, i need to add a button to upload file.

```
<input type="file" style="width:100px" name="file" id="file" ng-model="FileName" class="inputfile ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" ng-model-instant accept="image/*" ng-click="angular.element(this).scope().UploadBlogPicture(event)" >
```

But the function UploadBlogPicture() is not triggering in my controller.

I tried
grid.appScope.angular.element(this).scope().function(),
grid.appScope.angular.element(this).appScope().function(),
ng-click,ng-change . But nothing is trigeering my function

I tried like this

1.

```
 { name: 'BlogFile', width: '25%', displayName: 'Blog File', cellClass: 'noPadding', cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ><input type="file" style="width:100px" name="file" id="file" ng-model="FileName" class="inputfile ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" ng-model-instant accept="image/*" ng-click="grid.appScope.angular.element(this).scope().UploadBlogPicture(event)" aria-invalid="false">', enableCellEdit: false },
```

2.

```
   { name: 'BlogFile', width: '25%', displayName: 'Blog File', cellClass: 'noPadding', cellTemplate: '<input type="file" style="width:100px" name="file" id="file" ng-model="FileName" class="inputfile ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" ng-model-instant accept="image/*" ng-change="grid.appScope.angular.element(this).scope().UploadBlogPicture(event)" aria-invalid="false">', enableCellEdit: false },
```

Please help to sort out the issue

Comment: Why not just `ng-click="UploadBlogPicture($event)"`?

Comment: ng-click is not working.. before it upload picture, it return from function

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you're using a cellTemplate for this, right?

If you're using the "Controller as", you need to define the appScope in the gridOptions, before using the "grid.appScope.function()":

```
vm.gridOptions = {
  appScope: vm
}
```

Or you can do "grid.appScope.vm.function()"
But it's better to use the appScope in the gridOptions.